# Setting a Playing Card Value

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have the following init statement for my NSObject class, KCCard.

```
- (id)initWithValue:(NSInteger)aValue suit:(Suit)aSuit {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.suit = aSuit;
        self.value = aValue;
    }

    return self;
}
```

Suit is either Clubs, Spades, Diamonds, or Hearts.
Value is 1 through 13.

My problem is that the values 11 through 13 are Jack, Queen, and King. But for a Blackjack game, their values are all worth 10. But if I set the cards value to 10, it thinks that the card is a 10 and when I get the image for the card, a 10 image is shown.

How can I make it so it knows that 11 through 13 are worth 10, but not interfere with the image of the card?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just simply write one more function to get the actual value. For example

```
- (int)actualValue  {
    int actualValue = self.value;
    if (actualValue > 10)  {
       actualValue = 10;
    }
    return actualValue;
}
```

So you use this function to check the value